# How can I start scheduler with starting adonis server

Tags: typescript, scheduler, adonis.js

I want to run the scheduler along with the server startup in adonis js. I want to schedule task but don't want to execute it with external command like

```
adonis run:scheduler
or
node ace run:scheduler
```

Is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own custom command by using ace or register a new script inside `package.json` for e.g inside your `package.json` script object add this property,

```
"serve:with-scheduler": "node ace serve & node ace run:scheduler"
```

and then use below to run simultaneously,

```
npm run serve:with-scheduler"
```

Comment: for some reason, I don't get console prints from the scheduler this way

Comment: This is may be because of two commands running in parallel. The quickest solution would be to pipe the output of these commands in separate files

Comment: That may very well be the issue. I just decided to instead run them in two consoles, to get the outputs that way